# How to bind to active route

Tags: scala, routes, scala.js, binding.scala

I'm using `com.thoughtworks.binding:route:11.0.0-M4` library for managing the routing, and until now I was implementing the thing by following the [TODO example](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/todo/blob/master/js/src/main/scala/com/thoughtworks/todo/Main.scala#L40-L43) (available in project github):

```
Route.watchHash(currentTodoList)(new Route.Format[TodoList] {
  override def unapply(hashText: String) = todoLists.find(_.hash == window.location.hash)
  override def apply(state: TodoList): String = state.hash
})
```

But in the version used, `watchHash` has been deprecated, and according to doc, `Route.Hash(state).watch()` should be used instead.

So, the form can be rewritten as following:

```
val route = Route.Hash[TodoList](all /* all todo lists*/)(new Route.Format[TodoList] {
  override def unapply(hashText: String) = todoLists.find(_.hash == window.location.hash)
  override def apply(state: TodoList): String = state.hash
})
route.watch()
```

But how can I retrieve (bind to) the current todo list when route changes ? The `Var(todolist)` that was given as argument is now internal to the `Route`.
Moreover `Route.Hash[]` is a `Binding[Unit]`, so I can't retrieve value like this: `route.bind.xxx`.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `route.state.bind.xxx`.

See [Route.Hash.state](https://static.javadoc.io/com.thoughtworks.binding/binding_2.12/11.0.0-M4/com/thoughtworks/binding/Route$$Hash.html#state:com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding.Var[PageState]).

Comment: Oh, yes, I missed that. Really simple.

Thank you very much for the quick response.